# $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ transformation: reflection across a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, linear-transformations, reflection

Notation: $v$// is $v$ parallel symbol,  $v\bot$ is $v$ perpendicular, and both are relative to plane $\sqcap$

Let $\sqcap \subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ be the plane whose equation is $x + y + z = 0$. Let $F\sqcap$ : $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$  be the reﬂection through the plane $\sqcap$: that is, for a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, if we write v = v// + v⊥, where $v$// $\in \sqcap$ and $v\bot$ is orthogonal to the plane $\sqcap$, then $F\sqcap(v)$ = $v$// $− v\bot$.

Determine the representing matrix $([F\sqcap]E \to E)$ of $F\sqcap$, where $E = \{e1, e2, e3\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

I know that $v\bot\bullet v$//$=0$, I don't think that tells me anything useful for this problem.

I know that $v-v\bot=v$//=$F\sqcap(v)+v\bot$, which yields $v-2v\bot=F\sqcap(v)$

the v and $-2v\bot$ term don't tell me enough for a full transformation because I don't have enough information to form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and define the transformation with respect to $E$.

Any clue is appreciated... I've been stuck on this since last night.

Comment: I outline related material in [this older answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/607578/11619). I hope that will help you, because I describe the general formula for a reflection w.r.t. a plane through the origin there. I'm sure there are many answers here, where that formula is derived.

Comment: @Eric I edited $\mathbb{R}^3$ insted of R3, is it ok?

Comment: thank you for the edit,

@JyrkiLahtonen, I read your older post, and I think the problem is asking me to derive the 'recipe' you posted.  I cannot tell from your answer how you arrived at the transformation s(x⃗ )=s(x⃗ )=x⃗ −2(x⃗ ⋅n⃗ )•n⃗ / ||n⃗||^2.. any further help is appreciated.

Comment: @Eric Use "mathjax" language

Comment: Eric, [in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/65525/11619) I derive that formula for a reflection in the plane. The same idea works: split the vector into two components: one parallel to the normal of the plane/line you reflect w.r.t., the other orthogonal to that. One component does not change in the reflection, the other gets multiplied by $-1$. Sorry about the murky picture. Also the asker of that question used programmer's notation for the coordinates of the points, so this may be unreadable. Looking for something better...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but if you can find a basis $V$ by first finding two linearly independent vectors in your plane (i.e. two linearly independent solutions to your plane equation, e.g. just plug in values for $x$ and $y$ to get $z$), and then one vector orthogonal to your plane (i.e. the vector of coefficients that define the plane), then the transformation with respect to this basis $V$is trivial, it's just the diagonal matrix $D$ with $(1,1,-1)$ on the diagonal. So then if you want the matrix of the same transformation, but with respect to the standard basis, it's just $VDV^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure where that D matrix came from.  Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Your help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @Eric Sure, all vectors on your plane are eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1, because the reflection doesn't affect them. On the other hand, a vector that is orthogonal to your plane is an eigenvector with eigenvalue -1 because it is totally reflected, i.e. sent to its opposite. You can only have 3 linearly independent eigenvectors so that completely characterizes the transformation. With respect to the basis $V$ so obtained, any vector is expressed uniquely as a linear combination of your two eigenvectors in the plane and the orthogonal eigenvector, and then the matrix $D$ applies.