# Turn matrix into a rotation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, rotations

Given the matrix $A = 1/7\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 3 & a_{13} & \\ -2 & 6 & a_{23} \\3 & a_{32} & a_{33}  \end{bmatrix}$

How do replace the $a_{ij}$'s with real entries such that the matrix becomes a rotation matrix?

I know it should have a determinant of - 1 and all eigenvalues should be either 1 or -1, but it turns out to be a four variables equation, how do I find those values?

Edit: I forgot the scalar in front of the matrix.

Comment: I think it would be easier to consider $AA^\top$ since for any orthogonal matrix $A$ we have $AA^\top=I$.

Comment: A rotation matrix is orthogonal.

Comment: All the entries of a rotation matrix are $\le 1$.

Comment: What the others said. You can, however, easily fill in the missing entries in such a way that $\dfrac17A$ is a rotation matrix. Furthermore, $\pm1/7$ are the only possible scalar multipliers that work.

Comment: In addition, rotation matrices have determinant $1$, and the eigenvalues *could* be $\pm 1$, but could also be complex numbers on the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Each column has to have length $1$, so
$$3^3+6^2+a_{32}^2=7^2.$$
This determines $a_{32}$ up to sign.
But the first two columns must be orthogonal, and that will
determine the sign of $a_{32}$.

Also the rows have to have length $1$. Therefore
$$6^3+3^2+a_{13}^2=7^2$$
etc.
So one gets the entries in the last column up to sign.
Orthogonality of rows means that one sign determines the others.
Finally a rotation matrix has determinant $1$, so this determines
the final sign.

Comment: You can also get the last column as the cross product of the other two.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Gordon Pall (1940) showed that all 3 by 3 **rational** orthogonal matrices come from one type of quaternion calculation, the same material as we get with "Pythagorean quadruples." The matrix is formula (10) http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Pall_Automorphs_1940.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference @WillJagy! Because I played with reflection groups in my youth I have been in the habit of getting rational orthogonal matrices as products of two reflections. Like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/607578/11619). I'm not sure I get all those matrices from that recipe. That we get them all from quaternions (probably rational) does not necessarily surprise me - even though I didn't know about it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen right, it may not be clear but you just use integers. So $7 = 2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2$ is the only correct sum up to order and $\pm$ signs, so matrix (10) always gives different versions of the 2,3,6 entries. My favorite paper is Jones and Pall (1939), this is in the same area  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jones_Pall_1939.pdf